# Why no link to "English" on "Programmers"?

Tags: discussion

Why is it so that when I scroll down the "Programmers" face web-page I can see (down below) links to almost all the web-pages that belong to "Stack Exchange" except the link to "English"?

(I know I am supposed to ask this question on "meta" instead of here, but in order to do that I have to have 5 points of reputation on "Programmers", which I am most likely a far cry from achieving as I have no expertise to answer any of the serious questions here)

Comment: I don't think a site is linked in the collective footer until it is officially out of beta.

Comment: Aah, I see. Thank you, Tim.

Comment: But then, why is Apple (among others) there? It's still in beta, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites that are in beta are segregated from the Stack Exchange community at large: when you're on Programmers.SE–a beta Stack Exchange site—you'll only see sites that are also in beta in the footer.

[English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com) is out of beta, so it no longer appears in the beta Stack Exchange footer.

You know a site is out of beta when it has its own theme instead of the "Sketchy" theme.

Comment: Aaah, I see. Thank You, Mark!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't speak English, only Pascal, C++, VB and C# :)

Comment: You don't even speak Python? :)

Comment: I'm a static kind a guy, not very dynamic at all. BTW, I can read Python, but I can't speak it fluently.